# Are there any Christian denominations that do not believe in Exorcisms?

Tags: denomination-survey, demons, belief, exorcism, demon-possession

I was recently reading "Hostage to the Devil" by Malachi Martin, and starting thinking about demonic possession and exorcisms. Naturally, when I thought about exorcisms the movie "The Exorcist" popped up. And then it struck me that "The Exorcist" and the book I was reading were both based on Catholic Exorcisms.

In Catholicism, we believe that during an exorcism, the exorcist (highly trained priest specifically for exorcisms) is actually battling the demon. There are certain prayers that go with it and there is a structure to it.

My questions is basically, are there any Christian denominations that do not believe in possessions/exorcisms, if not, then are there some that take it only as a very lose possession (a demon made me do it, but it's gone now)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am personally unaware of any denominations that would specifically deny as part of their creed demon possessions or exorcisms.  However there are many denominations that by ignoring this area of practical theology do about the same.  Many of the "liberal" denominations tend to deny the spiritual nature of things and think of things more in terms of mental issues than spiritual bondage, this attitude would also constitute a practical denial of exorcisms.